# Wrong conversion of the timestamp

Tags: c++, string, timestamp

I'm new with C++ and I have a problem in converts timestamp UNIX with c++ because the conversion is exactly one hour ahead, I think the error is stupid and is in the conversion of the timestamp in a string because the value of the timestamp is correct.

this is my code

```
string BlockHeader::convertTimeStamp() {
char data[30];
time_t timeToValue = time;
tm *tmTime = localtime(&timeToValue);
strftime (data,30,"%F %T", tmTime);
string dataString = string(data);
cout << dataString;
return dataString;
```

}

the value correct is `1231006505 -> 2009-01-03 18:15:05` but the value convert is `2009-01-03 19:15:05`

sorry for my horrible English but my learning.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's your configured timezone?

Comment: @eerorika Europe/Rome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the value correct is 1231006505 -> 2009-01-03 18:15:05

No, it isn't because

> Europe/Rome

Europe/Rome timezone is one hour ahead of UTC, and therefore 1231006505 *is* correctly 2009-01-03 19:15:05 in that timezone.

If you want the UTC time, then you need to use `gmtime` instead of `localtime`. *Local* in the function name refers to the *local* timezone.

Comment: I guess that he probably wants to convert the timestamp into UTC ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `gmtime` instead of `localtime`.

localtime takes into account your timezone (UTC +1 right now), gmtime doesn't.